# Find the position of difference between two strings

Tags: python

I have two strings of equal length, how can I find all the locations where the strings are different?

For example, "HELPMEPLZ" and "HELPNEPLX" are different at positions 4 and 8.

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
s1 = 'HELPMEPLZ'
s2 = 'HELPNEPLX'
[i for i in xrange(len(s1)) if s1[i] != s2[i]]
```

It will return:

```
> [4, 8]
```

The above solution will return a list with the indexes in sorted order, won't create any unnecessary intermediate data structures and it will work on Python 2.3 - 2.7. For Python 3.x replace `xrange` for `range`.

Comment: `zip` is an iterator in Python 3. Not sure what you mean by Python 2.3 comment.

Comment: It means that it doesn't use Python 3-specific features - like assuming that zip is an iterator, or that set comprehensions are available. My solution works efficiently even in older Python versions, as long as list comprehensions are available

Comment: Set comprehensions are in Python 2.7.

Comment: `xrange` doesn't exist in py3; it is renamed to `range`.

Answer (score 26):

Python really comes with batteries included. Have a look at [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib)

```
>>> import difflib
>>> a='HELPMEPLZ'
>>> b='HELPNEPLX'
>>> s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
>>> for block in s.get_matching_blocks():
...     print block
Match(a=0, b=0, size=4)
Match(a=5, b=5, size=3)
Match(a=9, b=9, size=0)
```

`difflib` is very powerful and a some study of the documentation is really recommended.

Comment: It is giving the similar sub-string positions, not the differences.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> s1 = 'HELPMEPLZ'
>>> s2 = 'HELPNEPLX'
>>> [i for i,(a1,a2)  in enumerate(izip(s1,s2)) if a1!=a2]
[4, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you store the two strings in `a` and `b`, you can loop through all the items and check for inequality.

*python interactive interpreter:*

```
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...   if a[i] != b[i]: print i, a[i], b[i]
... 
4 M N
8 Z X
```

---

Another way to do this is with list comprehensions.  It's all in one line, and the output is a list.

```
>>> [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != b[i]]
[4, 8]
```

That makes it really easy to wrap into a function, which makes calling it on a variety of inputs easy.

```
>>> def dif(a, b):
...     return [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != b[i]]
...
>>> dif('HELPMEPLZ', 'HELPNEPLX')
[4, 8]
>>> dif('stackoverflow', 'stacklavaflow')
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Don't use lambda when you don't have to: `def dif(a, b): return [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != b[i]]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, why not?  It does the exact same thing... as far as I know.  Is it just less Pythonic?  Or slower?

Comment: Lambdas are for *anonymous* functions and excellent for creating one liners.  Here, you assign a name to the lambda, which suggests that it would be better as a regular function.  Also, lambdas obscure your traceback when you have a bug..

Answer (score 2):

Pair up the strings character-by-character and iterate over this collection together with a counting index. Test whether the characters in each pair differ; if they do, output the index of where.

Using Python builtin functions you can do this neatly in one line:

```
>>> x = 'HELPMEPLZ'
>>> y = 'HELPNEPLX'
>>> {i for i, (left, right) in enumerate(zip(x,y)) if left != right}
{8, 4}
```

Comment: Although the OP didn't say so, I'd be willing to bet that a solution that produced the errant indices in ascending order would be preferable.

Comment: @Linus: if you want this, change the `{}` brackets to `[]`. That will give you a list comprehension instead of a set comprehension, so preserves the order.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the direction pointed by @FredrikPihl, here you have a solution that is also able to detect insertions/deletions using a module in the Python Standard Library:

```py
import difflib
a = 'HELPMEPLZ'
b = 'HELPNEPLX'
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b, autojunk=False)
for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
    if tag != 'equal':
        print('{:7}   a[{}:{}] --> b[{}:{}] {!r:>8} --> {!r}'.format(
            tag, i1, i2, j1, j2, a[i1:i2], b[j1:j2]))
```

With the output:

```
replace   a[4:5] --> b[4:5]      'M' --> 'N'
replace   a[8:9] --> b[8:9]      'Z' --> 'X'
```

Let's see how it works with a similar example including deletions and additions:

```py
a = 'HELPMEPLZ'
b = 'HLP NEE PLX'
```

With the output:

```
delete    a[1:2] --> b[1:1]      'E' --> ''
replace   a[4:5] --> b[3:5]      'M' --> ' N'
insert    a[6:6] --> b[6:8]       '' --> 'E '
replace   a[8:9] --> b[10:11]      'Z' --> 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to split data into two char arrays and then loop through comparing the letters and return the index when the two chars do not equal each other.

This method will work fine as long as both strings are equal in length.