# How do I find which characters are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Running this code

```
a =', my city is changing . The country is changing . '
b =', my city is changing . The country is changing . '
print(a == b)
```

gets me a `False`.

An editor highlights the difference. Click [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BJILIIGgD) to reproduce.

[image]

How do I get the difference programmatically with Python?

Comment: `How do I get the difference programmatically with Python?` What exactly do you want? Positions where the strings differ? Then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545492/find-the-position-of-difference-between-two-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
a =', my city is changing . The country is changing . '
b =', my city is changing . The country is changing . '
print([(i, t) for i, t in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if t[0] != t[1]])
```

which will print

```
[(21, ('\xa0', ' ')), (23, ('\xa0', ' '))]
```

This creates a list of 2-tuples for each character from each string and prints the indices of non-matching ones.